# How to hide div under another, transparent div but keep the body visible?

Tags: html, css, z-index, transparent

Since the filter element is sticky, the pictures will go under it as the user scrolls down, but it's transparent and the images become visible underneath it, which I want to hide while keeping the body background visible... I tried playing around with z-index which doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to get this done?

```
<div className="filter">
    <!-- some clickable tags to filter images -->
</div>
<div className="grid_filter">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
        ... 
        ... 
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.filter {
   position: sticky;
   top: 120px;
   background-color: #ee4d9070;
}

.grid_filter {
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
   grid-template-rows: auto;
   grid-gap: 50px;
}
```

Comment: *which I want to hide while keeping the body background visible* simply color the sticky element with the same background color of the body

Comment: body has a static background image, but i found another solution with a better result than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems I just discovered backdrop-filter, which in fact gives a better result when used with blur than I expected, it looks much better.